# Ampleness and Extensions of Line-Bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, sheaf-cohomology

I believe I have a proof that any vector bundle $V$ of rank $n$ on a projective variety $X$ has a filtration by line bundles (that is, there is a filtration $V = L_n \subset ... \subset L_0$, where $L_{i+1}/L_{i}$ is a line bundle for all $i$). This seems a little bit too good to be true. Could anybody verify my proof, or point out where the mistake is?

> Let $H$ be an ample line bundle on $X$. Then for some $p$, $H^p \otimes V$ has a global section, corresponding to an injection $\mathscr{O_x} \to H^p \otimes V$. This induces a exact sequence $0\to H^{-p} \to V \to M \to 0$, for a vector bundle M of rank $n-1$. By induction, $M$ has a filtration by line bundles. Hence, adding $H^{-p}$ to this filtration, so does $V$.

Answer (score 2):

This is not true.

First a counterexample: let $X=\mathbf P^2$ and $T$ the tangent bundle. I claim there is no exact sequence

$$ 0 \rightarrow L_1 \rightarrow T \rightarrow L_2 \rightarrow 0$$
where $L_1$ and $L_2$ are line bundles. To see this, note that by the Euler sequence, the total Chern class of $T$ is $c(T)=1+3H+3H^2$ where $H$ is the hyperplane class. It is then easy to check that $c(T)$ does not factor as $(1+aH)(1+bH)$ for any integers $a$ and $b$.

Why does your proof not work? It is because the injection you (correctly) find is only an injection *in the category of sheaves*. Such an injection need not induce injections on all fibres of the bundles in question, so the quotient need not be a vector bundle. For a more extreme illustration of the same idea, if $L$ is any line bundle with a global section, we get an injection $\mathcal O \rightarrow L$. But (unless $L$ is trivial) this map will be zero on some fibres, and the quotient will be a non-trivial torsion sheaf. The moral of the story is that vector bundles do not form a good category, which is part of the reason for working with sheaves instead.

Finally, let me mention a weaker result that is true: the existence of *Harder--Narasimhan* filtrations. I'll let you search for the details, but the idea is that we can find a filtration of any vector bundle whose quotients are semistable vector bundles, hence still "simple" in some sense.

Comment: One positive result is that if the rank of $V$ is larger than $\dim X$ then you can do some Bertini-type argument to show that there is some line sub-bundle.

Comment: @Hoot: nice! I don't think I have seen that. Can you give a reference?

Comment: @Nefertiti I think I'm making it sound more impressive than it is. I think it's an exercise in II.8 of Hartshorne. Using Grassmannians you can try to get a bigger bundle. Another thing to mention might be this "splitting principle" stuff. Splitting up bundles is a big business!

Comment: @Hoot: OK, I found it; Exercise II.8.3. As you say, not a huge deal, but it is always nice to hear about these tricks!